# geom_mark_ellipse runs forever

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm trying to plot the graph using geom_mark_ellipse.
I don't know why it runs forever without any error message.

First, I plot the normal scatter plot graph.
It runs successfully.

```
dailyActivity %>%   
  ggplot(aes(Calories,TotalSteps)) +
  geom_point()
```

But when I add geom_mark_ellipse as below, it runs forever.
any suggestion, please

```
dailyActivity %>% 
  ggplot(aes(Calories,TotalSteps)) +
  geom_point() +  
  geom_mark_ellipse(fill=UserType, label=UserType)
```

I did try to move fill and label inside aes(), still runs forever

```
dailyActivity %>% 
  ggplot(aes(Calories,TotalSteps)) +
  geom_mark_ellipse(aes(fill=UserType, label=UserType)) + 
  geom_point()
```

Here is the sample data [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R0dVa.png)

Comment: Provide us with a sample of the data you use so that we can help you, for example using `dput (dailyActivity)`

Comment: do you not need to have fill=UserType, label=UserType inside aes()

Answer (score 0):

thanks so much for great help.
Step to solve:

1. move fill and label inside aes()
2. install.packages('Rcpp') and library(Rcpp)